# What is the vim native way to apply math over pattern?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I need to re-factor a line with a repeated pattern in a way to apply some math over numbers. For e.g. let's assume the following line of code:

```
testpoints = [Point(1,2), Point(1,1), Point(1,2), Point(0,2), Point(2,2), Point(3,3), Point(1,3), Point(1,4), Point(2,3), Point(2,0), Point(2,1),]
```

and some function should be applied to all matches for e.g. (x, y) -> (x*10, y*10).

```
testpoints = [Point(10,20), Point(10,10), Point(10,20), Point(0,20), Point(20,20), Point(30,30), Point(10,30), Point(10,40), Point(20,30), Point(20,0), Point(20,10),]
```

The obvious solution is to add '*10' after both arguments:

```
:s/\(\d\+\)\(,\s*\)\(\d\+\)/\1*10\2\3*10/g
```

But, probably it will be better to do the math in the VIM. I tried with `:g`
**but with no success**:

```
:g/(\s*\d\+\s*,/normal 10<cr>af,w10<cr>a
```

The idea was to find the proper `(` and then to do 10 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> , then move to next number with <kbd>w</kbd> and again to increment ten times ...

Let me wrap up:

1. Is possible to be done this with `:g` command ?
2. Is there another more vim-native way for such substitution with math?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `sub-replace-expression` and `:help submatch()`:

```
:s/\(\d\+\)/\=submatch(1)*10/g
```

FWIW, the `:global` command is completely unrelated to the problem at hand.